# How to get n records from a Yii data provider?

Tags: yii

I have a model which has the following relationship declared:

```
'messages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'WallMessages', 'liga_id',
                'condition'=>'specific_post.parent_message_id IS NULL', 
                'order'=>'specific_post.date DESC', 
                'alias'=>'specific_post'),
```

Im trying to use this collection within a CListView with a custom pagination. However, if for example my pages are of size 5, i need to get from elements 5 through 10 to populate the view.. How can i get n elements from a defined relationship?

Answer (score 0):

you can use model's serach() or custom CDbCriteria yourself.
[CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria/)